# Splitting template literal to multiple lines isn't working

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

I am trying to split the template literal to multiple lines in an ajax call, but it's not working for me. Here's my code:

```
ajax.get(`${this.site}/_api/web/items?\
$filter=active eq 1\
$orderby=type,rank`)
```

When I do this, it doesn't consider the filtering and orderby that I have. I also tried with this:

```
ajax.get(`${this.site}/_api/web/items?
$filter=active eq 1
$orderby=type,rank`)
```

The actual URL in my code is actually longer than this, but this is basically what am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiline template strings, it includes a training newline character, `\n` in between the string literal which might not be what you want in case of an endpoint. You can just concatenate the string literals like so:

```
ajax.get(`${this.site}/_api/web/items?` +
    `$filter=active eq 1` +
    `$orderby=type,rank`
)
```

Comment: ... and in this case, unless the `$filter`/`$orderby` were actually meant to be `${filter}`/`${orderby}`, the 2nd and 3rd strings can even be plain string literals with either `"` or `'` as delimiters.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could just split it into multiple lines without having to use the + sign , but yeah seems it can't be done